# Pl/SQL Parsing csv file located over an http url and loading into the tables automatically

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have a requirement of automatically parsing csv file located over a http url (say http://example.com/report.csv) and loading into the table. How can I do it using pl/sql?

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. If you want answers, please show us what you've done and where exactly you run into problems. You can have a look at [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [Help](http://stackoverflow.com/help)

Comment: Have a look at package `utl_http`

Comment: @FrankOckenfuss - thanks! I will look into it.

Comment: @SejalParikh Have you gone through the Help section, especially the [**What topics can I ask about here?**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) part?

Answer (score 1):

It could be good idea to use external table.

First, define directory ([read more](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5007.htm)) where you will store your file:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY my_files AS '/usr/bin/my_files';
```

Then create external table ([read more](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/et_concepts.htm)) referring to the created directory:

```
CREATE TABLE SAMPLE_EXTERNAL_TABLE
  (C1 VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
    C2 VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
    C3 VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
    C4 VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
    C5 VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE))
  ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL
  (TYPE ORACLE_LOADER DEFAULT DIRECTORY "my_files" ACCESS PARAMETERS
    ( RECORDS DELIMITED BY '\r\n'
    CHARACTERSET AL32UTF8
    SKIP 1 --SKIPPING FIRST ROW(HEADER)
    fields terminated BY ';'
    optionally enclosed BY '"'
    missing field VALUES are NULL
    ) LOCATION ( "my_files":' report.csv' )) ;
```

Now you are able to insert all records from your CSV file (well, from external table) to target table:

```
INSERT INTO SAMPLE_TARGET_TABLE
  (COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3, COLUMN4)
SELECT * FROM SAMPLE_EXTERNAL_TABLE;
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code (from http://www.talkapex.com/2017/04/query-csv-data-using-apex-5-1-apis/) shows how to parse the CSV file in SQL:

```
select fname, lname, dept
from 
  (
    select 
      rownum rn,
      rtrim(regexp_substr(column_value, '([^,])*(,)?', 1, 1), ',') fname,
      rtrim(regexp_substr(column_value, '([^,])*(,)?', 1, 2), ',') lname,
      rtrim(regexp_substr(column_value, '([^,])*(,)?', 1, 3), ',') dept
    from table(apex_string.split(:data,chr(10)))
  )
where rn > 1
```

You can also get the CSV clob using `apex_web_service.make_rest_request` (https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-5.1/AEAPI/MAKE_REST_REQUEST-Function.htm#AEAPI1955)

Comment: make_rest_request sounds promising. I am gonna try it. Thanks.